# Webbrowser Navigate To PDF Files Does not Show Anything

Tags: c#, pdf, browser, show

I am trying to Impersonate and show the Pdf files from another computer in my network. The problem is, webbrowser goes and finds the pdf files but returns as a gray window. I guess it means that it can see the pdf but cannot load or something like that. Because when I change the path it says "The page cannot be reached". I searched about it for a couple days but couldn't find solution. I think there is no problem on impersonation because I can copy or delete or recreate the files with my program but cannot see :D Another interesting thing is when I navigate to a image file, no problem occurs. It works perfectly. Here is my code:

```
public class Impersonate : IDisposable
{
    private static string m_UserName = "myUserName";
    private static string m_Password = "mypassword";
    private static string m_Domain   = "myDomain";

    private IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
    WindowsImpersonateContext person;

    public void Dispose()
    {
         Undo();
    }

    public WindowsImpersonateContext Person()
    {
         bool success = LogonUser(m_userName, m_Domain, m_Password, 9, 0,                           
                                  ref token)

         if(success)
         {
              person = new WindowsIdentity(token).Impersonate();
              return person;
         }
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
         person.Undo();
         Closehandle(token);
    }
}


using(Impersonate imp = new Impersonate())
{
    imp.Person();
    string fpath = "Path_to_the_pdf_file";

    newWebBrs.Navigate(new Uri(fpath));
    newWebBrs.Show();
    newWebbrs.Refresh();
}
```

The 'using' part is under a button. Any help or idea will be appreciated :D

Comment: This problem can be related to adobe version installed on your pc please check the link https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/pdf-opens-grey-screen-browser.html

Comment: Does C# Webbrowser use adobe installed on my pc or it uses its own? If the first one is true, I cannot understand because I can open it manually via file explorer and adobe, if the second one is true I guess i have to update my VS.

Comment: Can you please open your local pdf file and check

Comment: I did. It showed me. I am disconcerted. A few days ago, i tried to open it on network and it worked, after 15 mins, it falled again (believe or not) with no code change. Since then, I cannot open. Now I am trying to handle if there is a Undo() or CloseHandle() problem. But cannot see the light at the end of the road :D